Do presidential vetoes increase the likelihood of political gridlock, or does it resolve gridlock?
Before we begin, let me clarify what I mean by “gridlock”—specifically, gridlock between the legislative and executive branches in the U.S. presidential system. My understanding is that this type of gridlock occurs when one branch’s legislative agenda is obstructed by the other. In this context, there exist two possible scenarios in which such gridlock could occur:

(a) When Congress refuses to pass the President’s proposed policies,

or

(b) When the President vetoes bills passed by Congress.

Does this definition accurately reflect the concept of gridlock between the two branches?
If so, based on scenario (b), would it make sense to say that presidential vetoes increase the likelihood of gridlock between the two branches? Or could it be argued that vetoes actually help resolve gridlock?

How could it resolve gridlock? Are you suggesting that the legislature won't waste time discussing and passing laws that they know will be vetoed, so they'll have more time to work on productive legislation?

But if the two branches have conflicting agendas, neither of them is being advanced, which is the definition of gridlock.

Increases, by design.
The constitution of the USA isn't designed to make it easy to pass new laws. The framers and interpreters of the constitution generally thought that statute laws were an undesirable necessity and deliberately put multiple points at which they could be stopped: The people (through their representatives), The States (through the senators) and the government (in the person of the President) must all concur to create new laws. If any of these three sources of power don't agree with a proposed law, it doesn't pass. (This, at least, is the theory)
Having "gridlock" is not a failure of the system, it is the way that the system is supposed to work. It is the system working to prevent laws from being passed. The Presidential veto is part of this system designed to prevent laws from being passed. It naturally increases the chance of "gridlock", as that is its purpose.

Of course, what was not anticipated was the role that political parties would play in Federal politics. It was generally expected that the divisions would be between States, not between "left" and "right" (however defined) The notion of a President being from a different party to the majority in Congress was not foreseen, as the President was not expected to be a representative of a party at all
